# Web-based email-html generator

Tags: html, css, email, web-applications, wysiwyg

I have a web application that allows users to build a 'client list.' We want to add a feature that allows the user to send email campaigns to that client-list through our web app. Right now we just have two textarea's where the user can input the HTML & plain-text versions of their email, and our system will take care of sending out the emails.

We'd like to give the user the ability to construct the email visually (wysiwyg type editor) within our web application. Does anyone know of a web-based javascript plugin to build html emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have always been a big fan of JWYSIWYG

https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg